# “MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP” request returns NULL in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, http, msxml

That's my first time trying to implement HTTP requests in SQL Server to get a JSON object and insert in my DB, but for some rease is always returning NULL for me.

I'm using [Json placeholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com) to test it but no success.

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO



Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(max);
Declare @Body as varchar(max);

Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
EXEC  sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get','https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos', 'false'

Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send', null, @body

Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT
Select @ResponseText as response
```

Response:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure but perhaps you need to comment out `setRequestHeader` line (you're not sending anything) and replace `Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT` with `Exec sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT`. I believe response text is a property.

Comment: Please, for your own sanity, consider doing this from client code and not directly from SQL Server. As you've discovered, the troubleshooting experience is terrible, and you need to be careful about not leaking resources (by forgetting to call `sp_OADestroy` -- which your code indeed omits). That you *can* make HTTP requests from within SQL Server definitely does not mean you *should*.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```sql
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);
```

or

```sql
Declare @ResponseText as NVarchar(4000);
```

instead of

```sql
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(max);
```

Answer (score 1):

-- Important for large respone:

```
SET TEXTSIZE 2147483647

Declare @ResponseText as nvarchar(max);

DECLARE @responseTextTable table(responseText nvarchar(max));
```

...

```
insert into @responseTextTable (responseText)
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText'
 
select @ResponseText = responseText from @responseTextTable
```

Comment: saved my day, response over 4k silently retuned `null` from `sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @resp` with resp declared as `varchar(8000)`. this approach works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and the issue was the protocol https when I changed the url to http I was able to receive a response back from the api. To call the api over https , Create a Library and run it in the SQLCLR

This will help you get started
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/database-objects/getting-started-with-clr-integration?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Having had a similar issue, what solved it for me in the server was setting the proxy.

```
EXEC @Result = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0', @Obj OUT
if @Result <>0 exec sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Obj

exec @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, 'setProxy', NULL, '2', 'http://yourProxyHere'
if @Result <>0 exec sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Obj
```