# sp_OAMethod always returns NULL when consuming a Rest API

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

sp_OAMethod always returns NULL when consuming a Rest API... I'm have no idea where the problem could be. Here is the source code of the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MakeCEPAbertoRequest
    @cep VARCHAR(8) -- Tamanho do CEP no Brasil
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @token VARCHAR(1000) = 'Token token=d142c65bc45454595b15897e1d70c04b6';
    DECLARE @url VARCHAR(1000) = 'https://www.cepaberto.com/api/v3/cep?cep=' + @cep;
    DECLARE @requestResult NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @Stat  INT 
    DECLARE @resposta NVARCHAR(4000)
    
    -- Criar um objeto XMLHTTP
    DECLARE @objectID INT;
    EXEC @Stat = sp_OACreate N'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @objectID OUT;
    
    -- Abrir a conexão para o URL desejado
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @objectID, N'open', NULL, N'GET', @url, false;
    
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @objectID, N'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'
    -- Definir o cabeçalho de autorização
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @objectID, N'setRequestHeader', NULL, N'Authorization', @token;
    
    -- Enviar a solicitação
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @objectID, N'send';
    
    -- Obter a resposta
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @objectID, N'responseText', @requestResult OUTPUT;

    -- Destruir o objeto XMLHTTP
    EXEC sp_OADestroy @objectID;
    
    -- Retorna a resposta
    SELECT @requestResult AS Response
END
GO
```

I have created the equivalent of this procedure with CLR but the behavior is the same (I always get NULL output).

When I use this API in Insomnia (with the same parameters) I get the expected response.

Comment: Do any of the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58837871/msxml2-serverxmlhttp-request-returns-null-in-sql-server) solve your problem?

Comment: Each of the `sp_OA*` procedures have a return status that should be consulted to see if they were successful or not. When unsuccessful you can invoke [`sp_OAGetErrorInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-oageterrorinfo-transact-sql) to find out what went wrong, such as that the site's SSL certificate expired some time ago. Did you configure Insomnia to ignore certificate errors?

Comment: I would ask why are you using those old object in the first place? They are more for compatibility with old SQL Server 2000 databases. If you want to communicate with an API use middleware. If you "must" don't in SQL Server, write a CLR function.

Comment: TSQL is not a generalized scripting tool, don't abuse it. You could do this in a couple  lines of Powershell `$token = "whatever"; $cep = "whatever"; (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.cepaberto.com/api/v3/cep?cep=$cep" -Headers @{ "Accept" = "application/json"; "Authorization" = $token }).Content`